# WooCommerce Conditional Product fields

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My client sells candles and melts and various items like that. She also creates her own fragrances. As a result, her candles (for example) have somewhere north of 200 fragrances. She has previously categorised these as Feminine or Floral fragrances etc.

I'm trying to get conditional fields on a product page to make it easier for a customer to narrow down what they want without having to scroll through 200+ fragrance names.

Do you know of any plugin or any way that would allow me to have conditional fields whereby the user selects a fragrance type (Floral for example) and then a drop down appears with all the Floral fragrances in there?

I've tried product attributes, but as they can't be mixed - variations don't work and a single attribute type means they're gonna be scrolling through a ton of options before find what they want.

Comment: Looking like this does it: https://www.wpdesk.net/products/flexible-product-fields-pro-woocommerce/

Comment: WooCommerce supports product categories.  Why wouldn't you just use those?  A product can be in multiple categories.

Comment: This is true. But Categories are mainly for filtering via the front end etc. If you have a single item in 200 categories. If someone buys it, how do you know which 'category' they want?

I need something that would notify the seller that the customer wants a 'candle' (which is in 200 categories) that smells like 'whatever'.